# Share purchases without sharing payment method with Family

Tags: iphone, icloud, sharing

I just found out that all of the purchases made in my family account (Me, my girlfriend, my dad, and her dad) all get charged to my payment method after a week or two of random charges on my PayPal from Apple.

Apparently, this is tied to the purchase sharing feature of the Family. I'd still like to share my purchases, as my girlfriend uses apps that I bought, but I dont want to share the payment.

So I have 3 questions.

1. Can I enable sharing past purchases without sharing payment

If not, can I

2. Check who made what purchase and when

and

3. Can the family members choose to use a different payment method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just found out that all of the purchases made in my family account … all get charged to my payment method…

This is expected behavior. Per [Apple Support; How to share purchases with your family](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201079) it states the following

> **One adult in the family — the family organizer — pays for everyone's purchases**. You can share apps, music, books, and more

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

The idea is that a **family unit** where a designated parent/guardian sets up family sharing with one person responsible for permissions and the ability to control billing, thus the single payer setup. See below from the same link.

> When you turn on purchase sharing, everyone in your family gets access to apps, music, movies, TV shows, and books that family members buy. **The family organizer is billed for family members' purchases**.

Technically speaking, your girlfriend isn’t part of the family unit (yet).  iCloud has many mechanisms to share items (pictures, documents, calendars, etc.) without having to be part of a family plan.

If you want your girlfriend as part of the family plan, but want to regulate purchases, you’ll need to enable [Ask to Buy](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201089)

#### TD;DR

Answering your questions (in order)…

1. Workaround.  You can share all purchases and prevent people people from making purchases without authorization by enabling [Ask to Buy](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201089).
2. No.  Only one person, the organizer, has payment authority. This is by design.
3. No.  Same as prior answer. Family members cannot have their own payment methods.  If you need this, remove them from the family plan and manually share the services (Photos, Calendar, Files, etc.) as needed.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I enable sharing past purchases without sharing payment

No, sharing purchases is tied to sharing payment methods. This is likely to prevent people overusing this feature.

You can ask all members of your family to keep a balance on their accounts, which will always be billed first, and only by them. Balances are *not* shared.

> Check who made what purchase and when

When you receive the email receipt, it will detail who made the purchase and on what device. The purchaser's Apple ID will be shown in the Apple ID field of the receipt, and the name of the device used will be shown under the purchased items.

Additionally, the Bill To will show payment methods - this will indicate whether it was charged to Account Balance (of the purchaser) or to your shared card. If it was split across two methods, the subtotal lines will indicate the breakdown.

> Can the family members choose to use a different payment method.

Family Members can load a balance onto their account and charge it directly. Otherwise, they have to use the family payment method, or disconnect from purchase sharing.